# Check and uncheck the child tree layers created by using a graduated renderer

Tags: pyqgis, visibility, categorized-renderer, layertree

My PyQGIS script creates a number of layers, including one with a Graduated symbol renderer "DE Single", which splits my line symbols into 8 ranges e.g. -150 to -105.

I have PyQGIS code to access the "DE Single" layer and make it visible or invisible (checked/unchecked), but I cant work out how to write the PyQGIS to check/uncheck each of the ranges individually.

"DE Single" is constructed by the deSingle object and the constructed layer is called layer line.

With the PyQGIS as follows:

```py
layer = root.findLayer(deSingle.layerLine.id())    
layer.setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

I can select the group node of all the 8 ranges, but I can't work out how to get to each of the children, e.g. only uncheck the range layer -75 to -70 etc.

[image: Table Of Contents - Tree]

If I add the code:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('DE Single')[0]

ranges_to_uncheck = ['-75 to -70',
                    '-95 to -85'] # Add more ranges as you like

tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()

model = tree_view.layerTreeModel()

layer_tree_layer = model.rootGroup().findLayer(layer.id())

# If the code in your question was working you could try this..
#layer_tree_layer = model.rootGroup().findLayer(deSingle.layerLine.id()) 

nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(layer_tree_layer)

for n in nodes:
    if n.data(Qt.DisplayRole) in ranges_to_uncheck:
        # Set unchecked
        n.setData(0, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        # To set checked...
        #n.setData(2, Qt.CheckStateRole)
```

I get:

> IndexError: list index out of range on the first line...

on the:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('DE Single')[0]
```

So if I replace the find with:

```py
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer = root.findLayer(deSingle.layerLine.id())
```

and now the code addition becomes:

```py
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer = root.findLayer(deSingle.layerLine.id())   

ranges_to_uncheck = ['-75 to -70',
                    '-95 to -85'] # Add more ranges as you like

tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()

model = tree_view.layerTreeModel()

layer_tree_layer = model.rootGroup().findLayer(layer.id())

# If the code in your question was working you could try this..
#layer_tree_layer = model.rootGroup().findLayer(deSingle.layerLine.id()) 

nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(layer_tree_layer)

for n in nodes:
    if n.data(Qt.DisplayRole) in ranges_to_uncheck:
        # Set unchecked
        n.setData(0, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        # To set checked...
        #n.setData(2, Qt.CheckStateRole)
```

on the:

```py
layer_tree_layer = model.rootGroup().findLayer(layer.id())
```

line I get:

> AttributeError: 'QgsLayerTreeLayer' object has no attribute 'id'

any ideas please?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The commented line in my answer was meant as the alternative way to get your `QgsLayerTreeLayer` object.

Comment: Hey thank you so much , this worked perfectly. I had no idea that this is how the API works. Its not obviously in the cookbook? unless I missed something. The ranges, are not really child layers as I thought?. I have updated my class that creates the graduated renderer to include some methods to take an index and created the range labels needed. Awesome thanks again!.

Answer (score 5):

The snippet below should work:

```py
ranges_to_uncheck = ['-75 to -70',
                    '-95 to -85'] # Add more ranges as you like

tree_view = iface.layerTreeView()

model = tree_view.layerTreeModel()

layer_tree_layer = model.rootGroup().findLayer(deSingle.layerLine.id()) 

nodes = model.layerLegendNodes(layer_tree_layer)

for n in nodes:
    if n.data(Qt.DisplayRole) in ranges_to_uncheck:
        # Set unchecked
        n.setData(0, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        # To set checked...
        #n.setData(2, Qt.CheckStateRole)
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.